# /public_html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat - LAMP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I currently have one domain set up on my LAMP server, and I want to add another one. I tried doing it myself but when I ran into issues, I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

I had example.com set up and it was working fine, all traffic would redirect to its https and I want to continue that. I am now getting as an error message after trying to restart the apache2:

```
script '/var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
```

I've searched my apache2.conf file for `httptest.php` but nothing matched.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.ca
    Redirect permanent / http://test.ca
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt

    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.ca/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt

    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.ca
    Redirect permanent / http://test.ca
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:444>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.ca/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file says (It has my ip instead):

```
127.0.0.1 myservername
```

When I do a `ls -l` in /var/www/html/ I get:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 15 20:49 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jan 11 19:19 test.ca
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec 15 21:00 example.com
```

then changed it to:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 15 20:49 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Jan 11 19:19 test.ca
drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Dec 15 21:00 example.com
```

I've ran the code below and it says its enabled for both:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
sudo a2ensite test.ca
```

The error occurs on apache restart.

Comment: hello,  I wanted to ask if you solved that error with SSL certificate?

Comment: I resolved it with the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you activated your virtual hosts? If not ... 
Activate hosts with the built in apache shortcut:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
sudo a2ensite test.ca
```

And restart Apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also check permissions of your project folders

Comment: Yes I've done this, I get the error when restarting apache2

Comment: `script '/var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat`

Comment: is there in `/etc/hosts` file the following entry: `127.0.0.1 example.com test.ca` ?

Comment: It has my server ip then the hostname so looks something like: `##.###.###.### serverName`

Comment: something like: what?

Comment: I thought it was in the edit, my server ip then hostname. `127.0.0.1 myserver`

Comment: any ideas? Is there anything else I can show to help debug the problem?

Comment: also check for proper permissions

Comment: permissions on what? Which file?

Comment: `/var/www/html/test.ca` and `/var/www/html/example.com/`

Comment: After doing a `ls -l` it says `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 15 20:49 index.html`
`drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jan 11 19:19 test.ca`
`drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Dec 15 21:00 example.com`

Comment: that's it. Your project files should NOT be under `root` user. Change permissions with `chmod` and `chown`

Comment: I've change the permissions to `sys` so `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Dec 15 20:49 index.html`
`drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Jan 11 19:19 test.ca`
`drwxr-xr-x 4 sys  sys   4096 Dec 15 21:00 example.com` but I still get the same error when trying to restart the apache2

Comment: Was it like: `chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/test.ca` ?

Comment: It seem to remove this error. I'm getting another one so I'll open a new question/look for the solution first. Probably update your answer

Comment: maybe, I would help you with that new question if you let me know

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm getting this error: `[Thu Jan 14 06:56:12.164955 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3573] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)`